# Error after opening a file in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I created a C# class file and tried to open it in Visual Studio for Mac, but when I do an error pops up saying:

[image]

> Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "MonoDevelop.TextEditor.CocoaTextViewImports" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.

How do I open this `*.cs` file?

Comment: Looks like a corrupt extension database or corrupt MEF cache. I would try closing Visual Studio for Mac, then delete the directory `~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/8.0/addin-db-003/` and then restart Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: @MatttWard it didn't work

Comment: I would file a bug on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html and attach the full IDE log after reproducing theproblem.

Comment: Well, it fixed it for me. Thanks @MattWard!